# How to Select last Column in a row on mysql?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

How to Select last Column in a row on mysql?

For a table like this:

```
  ID   qty1    qty2    qty3    qty4   qty5   qty6    qty7 
   1    20      10       90     40     0       0      0
   2    90      80       0       0     0       0      0
```

The result should be:

```
ID   last_column_value
 1          40
```

or

```
ID   last_column_value
 2          80
```

Usually I use Select Max(ID) from table if I need last value on 1 column.

Comment: My Question is not duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I can see to solve it is to do a nasty nested IF as below.

```
SELECT ID, IF(qty7 <> 0,qty7, IF(qty6 <> 0,qty6, IF(qty5 <> 0,qty5, IF(qty4 <> 0,qty4, IF(qty3 <> 0,qty3, IF(qty2 <> 0,qty2, qty1)))))) last_column_value
FROM qtytable
```

This results in

```
ID  LAST_COLUMN_VALUE
1   40
2   80
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ef68d0/14)

Comment: Thanks. It Veryb helpfull, I just know Select Query can use IF.